# Проблема с переадресацией

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте . Сделал автоматическою переадресацию с помощью htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (az|hy|be|kk|ky|mo|ru|tg|tk|uz|uk) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://site.com/ru/ [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://site.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Все работает но проблема в том что после переадресации например сайт работает на английском языке (главная директория) но другии языки русский (/ru) и т.д. но если кто то хочет поменять язык например с русского на английский то он попадает на главную директорию т.к. там находится htaccess он автоматически перенаправляет снова на русский язык (/ru) . Надеюсь смог объяснить :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем переадресовываете во втором случае, если запрос и так пришел на `/`.

Попробуйте убрать последний Rule

Думая для поисковиков этот вариант не подойдет. Добавьте исключение для `user-agent *Bot`

Следует создать отдельный url для английского языка, иначе переключение будет невозможно, будет циклическая переадресация.

Comment: Спасибо но не помогло )

Comment: Другие правила есть в файле?

Comment: Другие есть но не связанные с переадресацией

Comment: Переадресация происходит по ссылку /ru/ или /ru ?

Comment: Переадресация происходит по ссылке /ru/ . Но вы кажется меня не поняли . Проблема не в переадресации а после переадресации

Comment: Поясню логику текущей работы .htaccess: Если пользователь запрашивает "корневую" страницу И язык, принимаемый браузером, из списка (....), переадресовывать на /ru/

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь переадресовать пользователя с браузером, который принимает языки (....) снова на корневую "/" процесс будет цикличен и не закончится) Реализовать лучше все-таки с использование разных URL: /ru/ и /en/ причем не будет достаточным определять язык браузера, лучше ввести, например куку

Comment: Спасибо большое . Думаю так сделаю для английского языка создам как и на других языках (/en) и с главной директории сделаю переадресацию .